# Highcharts Gantt Navigator // add border to milestone

Tags: highcharts

I have a Gantt Chart with a Navigator bar at the bottom that look like this:
[image]

The image as you can see is hard to read because of the color of the milestones... my question is, how do we get a white border on each of these milestones... I tried on almost everything the docs say, on series, datalabels, etc and I can't make any border show, thank you for any help you may bring.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify `borderWidth` and `borderColor` properties for the specific data points:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    series: [{
        ...,
        data: [
            ..., 
        {
            ...,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'black'
        }]
    }],
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xps2d6z3/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.borderWidth

https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.borderColor